# Using UDF output string in SQL SELECT Query?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a user-defined function (in Microsoft Access) that takes a value from two fields and returns a string, which corresponds to a column name.

This might not seem very clear; below is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do. Unfortunately I can't use the real problem as it's confidential.

Input:

```
 Num1 | Num2 | Field1 | Field2 | Field3 | Field4 | Field5

 .....|......|........|........|........|........|.......

 .....|......|........|........|........|........|.......

 .....|......|........|........|........|........|.......

 SQL query: "SELECT Num1,Num2,Func(Num1,Num2)
```

Output:

> Num1 | Num2 | FieldVal

In the output, FieldVal can be the value of Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4, or Field5, depending on Num1 and Num2. As of now I have a user defined function that determines which field's being used(1,2,3,4,or 5) based on two inputs (Num1 and Num2).

I guess what I'm trying to say is that I want to query a different column depending on Num1 and Num2.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Why not input Field1 to Field5 into `Func()` and have it determine which one of those to return?

Comment: @TimWilliams Because the data in fields 1 to 5 is independent of the field that needs to be returned (the selection of field is entirely dependent on Num1 and Num2)

Comment: Maybe you've oversimplified your real use case, but I'm not seeing why you can't perform the selection of Fieldx inside your function, based on Num1 and Num2.  It's difficult to offer suggestions based on the information you provide: for example we have no idea what logic is used in your function to evaluate Num1 and Num2 and thus select a field to return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `switch` statement, like:

```
select  switch(
        Func(Num1,Num2) = 1, Field1,
        Func(Num1,Num2) = 2, Field2,
        Func(Num1,Num2) = 3, Field3,
        ...)
```

Comment: Access doesn't support ’case’ afaik.

Comment: Sorry - I can see now that I messed up my explanation. The function actually outputs the field name ("Field1","Field2",etc). Your solution still works though - thanks! If I can't find something more robust then I'll stick to this... I didn't know you could do switch cases in SQL

Comment: Ouch, forgot about that. You can use `iif` like Manuel Castro suggests, or [`switch()`](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/switch.php) which I'll edit into this answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the IIF function, for example:

`SELECT 
       Num1, 
       Num2, 
       IIF(NUM1 < NUM2, Field1, IIf(NUM1 = NUM2,Field1, Field2))`

I've used operations `NUM1 < NUM2` and `NUM1 = NUM2` as examples, you could use any other operation as long as the result is boolean.

Note that I only detailed two nested `IIF` but you can nest as many as you need.

Read up for more: http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/iif.php